# Why is an inherited attribute null?

Tags: php

I am attempting to use some DI technique to remove the use of a service locator/registry in my application. This application is a learning exercise, and not production-ready.

I am currently using Pimple to hold references to new instances of class objects. The Parent class' attributes are being filled appropriately correctly.

Here's some code:

```
abstract class Parent 
{
    protected $dataService:
    protected $registry;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $constructorArgs = func_get_args();

        foreach ($constructorArgs as $arg){
            if ($arg instanceof Container){
                $this->registry = $arg;
            }
        }

        $this->dataService = $this->registry['DataService'];
    }
}


class Child extends Parent
{
    protected $dependency;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $constructorArgs = func_get_args();
        parent::__construct($constructorArgs);

        foreach ($constructorArgs as $i => $arg){
            if ($arg instanceof Dependency){
                 $this->dependency = $arg;
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Now, inside `Child`, if I try to access `$this->dataService` even through a getter (from the Parent), I am returned null.

I've checked and it looks like it is setting `$dataService` inside the Parent, but `Child` can't see it?

Comment: Remember that `func_get_args()` returns an array so if you're calling another one in parent constructor you're effectively getting array of array of original arguments. If that's the case, let me know and I'll post the answer.

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk as per the code, I'm calling `func_get_args()` in both the parent and child classes.

Comment: Are you sure it's setting `$this->registry` in the `Parent` class? I think it shouldn't, because you aren't forwarding the constructor properly. You're sending all the arguments to the parent function as one argument (an array), rather than as a list of arguments.

Comment: @bear Yes, but understand that if you instantiate Child by for example `new Child(12, 'x');` you get `array(12, 'x')` in child constructor and `array(array(12, 'x'))` in parent constructor and it seems that you loop over that in parent constructor in the same way as in child one. Please dump both `$constructorArgs` variables and you'll see for yourself.

Comment: @lonesomeday yep, did a `print_r()` as I can't debug it on this machine as I've ended up with a massive file of stuff in `$registry`.

Comment: Try looping over `$constructorArgs[0]` in parent constructor.

Comment: As a side question, if you're attempting to learn Dependency Injection, why don't you explicitly reference those dependencies in a constructor? Doesn't such approach defeat the purpose?

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk it works - I'd be grateful if you could post and answer in some detail about this, because I don't fully understand (I'm new to `func_get_args()`.

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk Well, `Child` is a module class which extends a base 'Parent', providing a set of standard functionality across the child classes. I thought about it, but I'm using a module configuration array to tell the DI container that `Child` has dependencies and needs to be instantiated with them

Comment: Answer posted, please comment and accept if it fits. TBH No need to extend that class, it's a mild violation to Open/Closed principle with such approach. You should pass service which handles common tasks as a dependency, not include them directly into classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `func_get_args()` returns **array** of arguments passed to given function or method. It means that in your Child class when instantiated like `$child = new Child(12, 'x');` you'll get `array(12, 'x')` in `$constructorArgs` variable. It's nothing fancy and a quite legitimate usage. But then you call parent constructor with that variable and again reading all arguments with `func_get_args()` which means that effectively you get array with one element - the array you've got in child constructor. So in parent constructor `$constructorArgs` is equal to `array(array(12, 'x'))`. You in your mind are still looping over that first array but in reality it contains one elements which is array of requested arguments. So you have two solutions here:

- you can loop over `$ConstructorArgs[0]` since with such implementation it'll contain requested values,
- or, which is in my opinion more sane, rather than calling `parent::__construct($constructorArgs)` you can call `call_user_func_array(array($this, 'parent::__construct'), $constructorArgs)` which will expand your arguments like a natural call and you don't have to change parent constructor because all arguments will be passed to it just like to Child's.

As a side note, if you're trying to learn Dependency Injection it's much better to explicitly pass arguments to constructors with proper typehints so both you and PHP interpreter will have all information just before your eyes, no need to loop over some strange arrays which can contain anything.

Comment: Yes, though note that `array($this, '__construct')` is not right, because it refers to the current function. It causes a segmentation fault on my build of PHP, because of the infinite loop.

Comment: Edited my answer, I did write it without running code, so that was unwillful omission on my side, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not forwarding the constructor call properly. You do this:

```
    $constructorArgs = func_get_args();
    parent::__construct($constructorArgs);
```

`func_get_args` gets the arguments as an array. That means `parent::__construct` will always receive precisely one argument: an array that contains all the arguments used in calling the child. You then call `func_get_args()` **again** in `parent::__construct`, which means you have a structure like this:

```
array(
    array(
        Container,
        otherData
    )
)
```

When you loop over that first array, your code checks to see if each item is an instance of `Container`. None of them are, because there is only one argument passed to `Parent::__construct` and it's always an array.

You want to forward the call so that the arguments are passed as arguments, not as an array. You can do this with `call_user_func_array`.

```
call_user_func_array(array($this, 'parent::__construct'), $constructorArgs);
```